# Turtle Events and Screen Coords

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This program moves a Turtle in 4 directions using keys. I want to control the
Turtle collision with the Screen boundaries too. But I'm having a very weird
problem!

For example, when I move the Turtle to the right side it works OK, but
when I turn the Turtle to the left side, graphically it turns OK but the coordinate values that `print` gives me, instead decreasing the X-coordinate value, increase one time and then start to decrease! Of course this messes up with the collision control I'm trying to create!

It's awkward, I just tested everything I could think of but so far got no luck!

I'm using Python 3.7.7 with Turtle graphics, in Thonny 3.2.7.
I tested it in Repl.it and the result was the same!

Here is the code:

```
import turtle

screen_width = 1000
screen_height = 800

s = turtle.Screen()
s.setup(screen_width, screen_height)
s.title("Python Turtle (Movimento)")
s.bgcolor("lime")

def turtleUp():
  t1.setheading(90)
  if not colisao(t1):
    t1.sety(t1.ycor() + 10)

def turtleDown():
  t1.setheading(270)
  if not colisao(t1):
    t1.sety(t1.ycor() - 10)

def turtleRight():
  t1.setheading(0)
  if not colisao(t1):
    t1.setx(t1.xcor() + 10)

def turtleLeft():
  t1.setheading(180)
  if not colisao(t1):
    t1.setx(t1.xcor() - 10)

def colisao(t):
  print(t.xcor(), t.ycor())
  if t.xcor() < -470 or t.xcor() > 460 or t.ycor() < -370 or t.ycor() > 360:
    return True
  else:
    return False

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.speed(0)
t1.shape("turtle")
t1.color("black")
t1.up()
t1.goto(0, 0)

s.onkeypress(turtleUp, "w")
s.onkeypress(turtleDown, "s")
s.onkeypress(turtleRight, "p")
s.onkeypress(turtleLeft, "o")

s.listen()

s.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue I see is that you check for collisions after a `setheading()` command, which can't itself cause a collision, and then do a `setx()` or `sety()` command that could cause a collision, but don't check for it!  It's as if you check for the previous move's collision on the next move.  The secondary issue I see is that you use various fixed values to calculate a collision rather than derive these from your screen width and height:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def turtleUp():
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 10)

    if colisao(turtle):
        # turtle.undo()
        turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 10)

def turtleDown():
    turtle.setheading(270)
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - 10)

    if colisao(turtle):
        # turtle.undo()
        turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 10)

def turtleRight():
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + 10)

    if colisao(turtle):
        # turtle.undo()
        turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - 10)

def turtleLeft():
    turtle.setheading(180)
    turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() - 10)

    if colisao(turtle):
        # turtle.undo()
        turtle.setx(turtle.xcor() + 10)

def colisao(t):
    return not(CURSOR_SIZE - SCREEN_WIDTH/2 < t.xcor() < SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - CURSOR_SIZE and \
        CURSOR_SIZE - SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 < t.ycor() < SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 - CURSOR_SIZE)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
screen.title("Python Turtle (Movimento)")
screen.bgcolor('lime')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

screen.onkeypress(turtleUp, 'w')
screen.onkeypress(turtleDown, 's')
screen.onkeypress(turtleRight, 'p')
screen.onkeypress(turtleLeft, 'o')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Many thanks cdlane. About the 2nd issue it was alright i was making some tests and one of the last ones i did i put some concrete values. No worries. Thanks again.